# How to transform a result set so column values become aggregated headers?

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, mysql-8.0

If I have a table:

| Id | Collection | Site |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Example Collection | stackoverflow.com |
| 2 | Example Collection | news.ycombinator.com |
| 1 | Example Collection | stackoverflow.com |
| 3 | Example Collection | reddit.com |
| 4 | Programming Sites | stackoverflow.com |
| 5 | Discussion Sites | reddit.com |

How can I transform it to...

| Collection | stackoverflow.com | news.ycombinator.com | reddit.com |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Example Collection | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| Programming Sites | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Discussion Sites | 0 | 0 | 1 |

In the real system which works similarly, there'll be 100k+ rows in the original table, and thousands of distinct "sites." It's desirable for the transformation to stay in SQL.

Comment: Done. MySQL 8.0.

Comment: Not possible without dynamic SQL.

Comment: This kind of transformation is better done in your application or frontend code. SQL is not designed to to that. Especially if you expect "thousands of columns" - most DBMS have a limit on the number of columns you can return. An alternative to returning "thousands of columns" is to aggregate this into a JSON structure. Not sure if MySQL can do that though. Do you have a list of all possible sites? That would be one prerequisite in order to get the zero counts

Comment: Yep, just handle this in your application code

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't hopeful it was going to be feasible, but worth the question. Implemented now in application layer. Was thinking the database may be able to do it more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have only those three sites, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select collection,
       sum(case when site = 'stackoverflow.com' then 1 else 0 end) as stackoverflow_com,
       sum(case when site = 'news.ycombinator.com' then 1 else 0 end) as news_ycombinator_com,
       sum(case when site = 'reddit.com' then 1 else 0 end) as reddit_com
from t
group by collection;
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry no, should have said, the list of "sites" in the example should be assumed to be variable (1,000+ in the real system which doesn't work with sites/collections but has a similar structure).

Comment: If you have thousands of sites, you might not even be able to return this as a table.